# HTTP Status 403 - GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Specified version of key is not available (44))

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

Im getting this error when I open oozie link.can someone help ?

HTTP Status 403 - GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Specified version of key is not available (44))

Im able to generate kerberos ticket in my local windows machine

Comment: From *Kerberos and Hadoop, the Madness beyond the Gate* section *"Error Messages to Fear"* > "The meaning of this message —or how to fix it— is a mystery to all ... Recommended strategy: rebuild your keytab" https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/errors.html

Comment: I Re-generated new keytab still getting the same error